# Create Column in Pandas Table with Coordinates that shows if coordinate was found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, coordinates

I have created a pandas data frame like the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("List-of-museums.csv", header='infer', sep=",")
from geopy import geocoders
df2 = df['Name'] #there are multiple museums in the column 'Name'. I would like to get their coordinates 

df2 = df2.tolist()

coordinates = []
for museum in df2: 
    g = geocoder.google(museum)
    coordinates.append(g.latlng)

comb = dict(zip(df2,coordinates))
comb = pd.Series(comb, name='Coordinates')
comb = comb.to_frame()
                             Coordinates
18 Stafford Terrace          [51.500476, -0.1968857]
2 Willow Road                []
575 Wandsworth Road          []
7 Hammersmith Terrace        []
Anaesthesia Heritage Centre  []
Apsley House                 [51.5034719, -0.1516708],[41.5034719,-0.1516708]
```

Desired output:

```
                                 Coordinates                  Count
 18 Stafford Terrace             [51.500476, -0.1968857]      1
 2 Willow Road                   []                           0
 575 Wandsworth Road             []                           0
 7 Hammersmith Terrace           []                           0
 Anaesthesia Heritage Centre     []                           0
   Apsley House                  [51.5034719, -0.1516708],[41.5034719,-0.1516708]                                           2
```

Hence, we added the last column which shows whether coordinates were found or not and if so, how many.

Comment: I can't wait for your code!!

Comment: I am a little confused: What is the desired output for the dataframe you've provided? What `location` means in your context?

Comment: By each location, I mean for each Name.

Comment: why does it not make sense?

Comment: Well now that you have modified your question it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['x','y','z', 'z1'],
                   'Coordinates':[[[1,2], [2,4]],[4,7],[4,5], []]})

print (df)
        Coordinates Name
0  [[1, 2], [2, 4]]    x
1            [4, 7]    y
2            [4, 5]    z
3                []   z1

def recursive_len(item):
    if type(item) == list:
        return sum(recursive_len(subitem) for subitem in item)
    else:
        return 1

df['count'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(recursive_len) // 2
print (df)
        Coordinates Name  count
0  [[1, 2], [2, 4]]    x      2
1            [4, 7]    y      1
2            [4, 5]    z      1
3                []   z1      0
```

Another solution is:

```
df['count'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(len) // 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!! Actually the Name does not repeat itself though. So, imagine: 
  Coordinates      Name
0      [1, 2], [2,4]    x
1      [4, 7]             y
2      [4, 5]             z

From this I would like to count how many times a coordinate appears for the name.

Comment: Also, sometimes there is no coordinate and the cell is just blank. Based on that I would like to have 0 in the count column

Comment: what is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'Coordinates']))` ?

Comment: Can you modify your answer with sample data and desired output?

Comment: Ok, so try `print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'Coordinates']))`

Comment: please see above :)

Comment: please check if works for you `df['count'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(len)`

Comment: it works, however, because a coordinate has two values, i get '2' in the count column for every coordinate. is it possible to use an arithmetic function in the apply function?

Comment: Do you need divide by `2`? like `df['count'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(len) / 2` ?

Comment: How can I convert the whole pandas data frame to a dictionary?

Comment: Use `df.to_dict()` - see [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: For some reason my table has 278 rows × 2 columns instead of 278 rows × 3 columns. Hence the count is not taken into consideration for the dictionary.